# How to count only one row when there are duplicates with specific criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say there are two tables Customer and Order:

Customer:

| CustomerID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam |
| 2 | Terry |

Orders:

| OrderID | CustomerID | Status | CreatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Cancelled | 8/30/2021 8AM |
| 1 | 1 | Cancelled | 8/30/2021 9AM |
| 1 | 1 | Pending | 8/30/2021 10AM |
| 2 | 2 | Cancelled | 8/22/2021 8AM |
| 2 | 2 | Pending | 8/31/2021 1PM |

If an order is placed on the same day, I want to capture the row with the latest datetime or biggest OrderID. If an order is placed on different days, I want to capture the first datetime the order was placed, regardless of status. I have only been able to query each of these conditions separately, but not together. OrderID should be unique in this query.

Expected query output:

| OrderID | CustomerID | Status | CreatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Pending | 8/30/2021 10AM |
| 2 | 2 | Cancelled | 8/22/2021 8AM |

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions for these conditions:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             min(createdate) over (partition by orderid) as min_createdate,
             max(createdate) over (partition by orderid) as max_createdate,
             row_number() over (partition by orderid order by 
createdate asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by orderid order by 
createdate asc) as seqnum_desc
      from orders o
     ) o
where (min_createdate = max_createdate and seqnum_desc = 1) or
      (min_createdate <> max_createdate and seqnum_asc = 1);
```